# Java - Migrating Twitter API 1.0 to 1.1

Tags: twitter, twitter-oauth, twitter4j

I want to modify twitter API from 1.0 to 1.1. The name of application which use twitter API is "diaryromantis". That application maker is not me and doesn't use twitter4j. 
And I add this : (This is from twitter4j)

```
ConfigurationBuilder cb = new ConfigurationBuilder();

String consumerkey = "xQ";
String consumersecret = "U";
String token = "787323";
String tokensecret = "n\I";


{   
    cb.setDebugEnabled(true)
      .setOAuthConsumerKey(consumerkey)
      .setOAuthConsumerSecret(consumersecret)
      .setOAuthAccessToken(token)
      .setOAuthAccessTokenSecret(tokensecret);
}

TwitterFactory tf = new TwitterFactory(cb.build());
Twitter twitter = tf.getInstance();
```

But the application still can't run.

Comment: I would suggest moving your secret keys, seeing as they are only meant for your eyes.

Comment: Also, please provide a complete (runnable) example (without your private keys) along with any associated errors.

Comment: FYI, the keys will be in the revision history, I would suggest revoking them.